# What is the meaning of the phrase "to this end"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Here is the entire sentence:

> **To this end**, we create two properties files with the correct root bundle name and the correct locale endings, one for English and one for Spanish.

(Emphasis added.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The definition in [MacMillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/end#to-this-end):

> **To this end** (Formal): **in order to achieve a particular aim**
>
> *He wanted to discuss his position, and
>   arranged a meeting to this end.*

Answer (score 23):

I think it's worth mentioning that this is not so much a figure of speech as it is a perfectly regular phrase involving a less common meaning of the word "end" as a synonym for "objective". This is most often seen in the saying, "The ends do not justify the means."

Comment: It's also a less common meaning of "to". You _can_ say "to this purpose", but "for this purpose" would be more normal.

Answer (score 18):

It means *"To accomplish the previously stated goal"*.

Answer (score 8):

Very common in formal UK English. It can mean "so/therefore/thus" as well as its basic meaning of "for this or that purpose"... In fact, here's one I wrote earlier today:

> Although IVF and embryo transfer are techniques widely used in mammals, they still present an important inexplicable percentage of failures.  To this end, studies are being carried out to elucidate the causes of failure.